# Why naive primality test algorithm is not polynomial

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I would like to understand why the following naive primality test algorithm is not polynomial.

```
IsPrime (n: an integer)
Begin
   For i=2 to n-1 do
     If (n % i == 0) then
        return (no)
     EndIf
   EndFor

   return (yes)
End
```

This algorithm is said to be **exponential in the size of the input *n***. Why is it true? And why the following sorting test algorithm is said polynomial and not exponential?

```
IsSorted (T[n]: an array of n integer)
Begin
  For i = 1 to n-1 do
     If (T[i] > T[i+1]) then
        return (no)
     EndIf
  EndFor

  return (yes)
End
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input size is typically measured in bits. To represent the number n the input size would be log2(n). The primitive primality test is linear in n, but exponential in log2(n).

Comment: So using the big-O notation, the complexity would be O(2^(log2(n)) which exponential ?

Comment: Yes, written a little differently O(2^k) where k is the input size in bits.

Comment: Thanks I now understand it better

Comment: How many bits do I need to encode and an array of n integers?

Comment: n times the size of an integer (=32) so 32n.

Comment: If each number is in k bits,  then the complexity of IsSorted should be O(nk) = O(n) since k is a constant that doesn't depend on the size of the input array. Am I right ?

Comment: To my understanding above statement is correct.

Answer (score 2):

To second the answer given by Henry, the algorithm in the original question in fact has a polynomially bounded running time - if *unary encoding* is used for the input!

More precisely, the runtime bound does not only depend on the algorithm itself but also the used encoding scheme. Consider the following algorithm in C-like syntax.

```
INPUT: integer n
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    wait one second
}
```

Apparently, the algorithm takes `n` seconds to terminate; the time is linear in `n`. If the input is encoded using *unary encoding*, the amount of time scales linearly in the encoding length of `n`. However, if `n` is encoded using *binary encoding* the amount of time scales exponentially in the encoding length of `n` (as the encoding length of `n` scales logarithmically in the value of `n`).

To put it all in a nutshell, the statement that the algorithm in the question is *not polynomial* without any additional information is not correct. However, apparently it is a convention that binary encoding (or any other positional notation) is used unless otherwise stated.

That being said, I admit that the depenence of the runtime bound on the encoding scheme tends to be taught a bit imprecisely. The term *pseudopolynomial* is also floating around.

Answer (score 2):

The naive primarily test is polynomial in the **value** of the input (that is, the actual number which the function receives), but exponential in the **size** (bits, bytes, etc.) of the input.

If you have a number `n` consisting of `b` bits, we have `b = O(log n)` and also `n = O(2b)`.

The running time is thus `O(n)` or `O(2b)`.