# difference between value of variable and size of variable in big O notation

Tags: python, big-o

I am studying cryptography algorithms. Here we have following algorithm to check primarality test.

```
def is_prime(x):
  for i in range(2,x):
    if x % i == 0: return False
  return True

On above following is quiz asked Would above approach work
A. Yes
B. No, its running time is exponential in the value of x
C. No, its running time is exponential in the size of x
D. No, there is a silly bug in python code
```

Answer is given as C.

My question and require help what is difference between value of 'x' and size of 'x'.

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Because the size refers to the numbers of bits used to represent the input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042838/why-naive-primality-test-algorithm-is-not-polynomial see the second answer in the link